# NbClust not showing any result when i run my code on RStudio

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

So here is my code. I want to know how many clusters that is optimal using the Single-Linkage Method. I have already installed the package for NbClust. But, when I run my code NbClust does not show anything as I showed in the picture. Does anyone know why this happened?

```
library("readxl")
data <- read_excel("z_housing.xlsx")    

install.packages("NbClust")
library(NbClust)
data.s <- scale(data[,-1:-2])
data.s
NbClust(data = data.s, distance = "euclidean",
        min.nc = 2, max.nc = 15, method = "single", index = "all", alphaBeale = 0.1)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error messages? What does `str(data)` show? When I try to replicate your code with the `iris` data set included with R, it works fine, just try using `data.s <- iris[, -5]` and then your code for `NbClust`. The output for the function is substantial so you should probably capture it, e.g. `output <- NbClust(....)` for later use.

Comment: Possibly you have a lot of data which takes a lot of time to render the graph.